# Bootstrapping as a way to deal with multilevel data (similar to Bayesian hierarchical models)

Tags: regression, bootstrap

Suppose you want to estimate the linear relationship between $x$ & $y$ among people. You can't afford to ask N = 100 people to measure the variables of interest and estimate the relationship, so instead you ask N = 20 people and you take repeated measurements from each individual (100 observation per person which makes a total of 2000 data points). But now your observations are not independent and are grouped with respect to individuals. You can run a linear regression for each individual separately and the relationship can be expressed as:

$$y = intercept_{j} + \beta_{j} \times x$$

$$j = 1,...,20$$

So you will have 20 different relationships ($\beta s$) which are individual specific but you are interested in the $\beta_{population}$ or the relationship in the population. Having a set of $\beta$ s ($[\beta_{1}, ...,\beta_{20}]$) I would take bootstrap samples from them (let's say 100 bootstrapped sample of the same size) and calculate their means to estimate the distribution of the $\beta_{population}$ (assuming $\beta_{j} \sim N(\beta_{population}, \sigma_{pop}^2)$) with its confidence intervals. Would this approach be reasonable or its not valid in ways that I can't see?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to draw one X×Y pair from each participant, construct β from those 20 points, and then repeat that a large number of times to get a distribution of β.

What concerns me about the method you proposed is that it seems to me you're throwing out information about the variability of the $\beta_j$.

One fairly straightforward way to test the validity of either approach is to make an artificial population, get the sampling distribution of β for that, and then try whatever method you have in mind drawing 20 from the full population and see what happens.

Comment: I simplified the problem here to not confuse people, but in my real problem there are more variables and 20 points are not enough for estimating the effects of those multiple variables, so that's why we have many more data for individuals to be able to estimate those effects at the individual level and then bootsrtap the parameters itself.